# Arduino stepper motor loop weird behaviour

Tags: c++, arduino

I am using a stepper motor with my Arduino and to turn it clockwise i made a function that turns the voltage of the wires on one at a time.
This works, however when i put the function in a loop it does not work.

The code is:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);  
}

void turnRight(int delayTime) {
  for(int i; i<=4; i++){
    digitalWrite(9+i, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10+i, HIGH);  
    delay(delayTime);
  } 
}

void turnLeft(int delayTime) {
  for(int i; i<=4; i++){
    digitalWrite(14-i, LOW);
    digitalWrite(13-i, HIGH);  
    delay(delayTime);
  }    
}

void loop() {

  int p=0;
  while(p<=100){
    turnRight(25);
    p++;

  }

}
```

The code makes the motor stutter, it goes left and right very quickly in kind of a vibrating motion, meaning the wires are probably turned on in the wrong order. However when i run this code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);  
}

void turnRight(int delayTime) {
  for(int i; i<=4; i++){
    digitalWrite(9+i, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10+i, HIGH);  
    delay(delayTime);
  } 
}

void turnLeft(int delayTime) {
  for(int i; i<=4; i++){
    digitalWrite(14-i, LOW);
    digitalWrite(13-i, HIGH);  
    delay(delayTime);
  }    
}

void loop() {

  int p=0;
  while(p<=100){
    turnRight(25);

  }

}
```

It does work, the motor runs smoothly and it does not stutter, the only difference is that i don't increment p in this code.
Using a for-loop gives the same effect, incrementing the for-loop value makes the motor stutter.

Comment: In functions ``turnRight`` and ``turnLeft``, for loops have not been initialized with specific value like ``int i=0``. I did not get this part.

Comment: Wow, youre right and i just added the "= 1" part and it fixed the problem somehow. If you want you can post your answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functions `turnRight` and `turnLeft`, for loops have not been initialized with specific value like `int i=0`.I think this is the part which causes problem.